# Get text field of search bar iOS 7.1

Tags: uitextfield, uisearchbar, ios7.1

Does anybody knows how to get the UITextField from any UISearchBar on iOS 7.1, i need to change the font and search icon but the old code doesn´t work with the new version 7.1, Thanks for your help.

This is the old code to get the UITextField, this only works on versions less than 7.1

UITextField *txfSearchField = [default_search_bar valueForKeyPath:@"_searchField"];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to search for it like this:

```
    for (UIView* subView in self.searchBar.subviews) {
        for (UIView* searchView in subView.subviews) {
            if ([searchView isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
                self.searchTextField = (UITextField*)searchView;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Doesnt work for IOS 7.1, Apperantly they changed the UITextfield to an internal class named UISearchBarTextfield.

Comment: Hi @ebf this code works fine for versions less than 7.1, but in 7.1 there is only one UIView and it´s UISearchBarBackground not UITextField, thanks for your help.

Comment: And I just confirmed. It works. The TextField is inside the UISearchBarBackground.

Comment: It doesn't work for me, it never enters to the "if" because the only view is UISearchBarBackground not UITextField, are you sure you are testing on iOS 7.1?

Comment: Finally it works like always, i don't understand why but i change the place where i was calling this function and it works fine, thanks @ebf.

Answer (score 2):

If you are in subclass of [UISearchBar](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchBar_Class/Reference.html) you can use simple fix.

Somehow after init there are not instances of UITextField in subviews.
But in - (void)layoutSubviews you can find it.

So the solution is to move code, that search for textfield out of init.
You can use this simple method, that will work on all iOS prior to 7.1

```
- (UIView *)firstViewOfClass:(Class)class inSubviewsOfView:(UIView *)view
{
    UIView *result = nil;
    for (UIView *subview in view.subviews)
    {
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:class])
        {
            result =  subview;
    }
    else
    {
        result = [self firstViewOfClass:class inSubviewsOfView:subview];
    }
    if (result)
    {
        break;
    }
}
return result;
```

}

Example of usage:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    if (!self.textField)
    {
        self.textField = (UITextField *)[self firstViewOfClass:[UITextField class] inSubviewsOfView:self];
    }
    [super layoutSubviews];

    // your code here.
}
```